# Creating subgroups - child groups ckan

Tags: ckan

I want to create subgroups/child groups in my CKAN installation, and have found mentions of it in the official ckan documentation, but there is nothing how it is implemented. Can someone give me a clue whether it is possible at all, and if it is, how it is done.

Thank you very much

Axlm

Answer (score 2):

The code in CKAN allows for arranging groups/organizations in a tree hierarchy. Via the CKAN API you can make a group a member of another group using package_update, and e.g. an admin for the top-level group will get permissions to the sub-group. However there is no default web UI to arrange groups in a hierarchy, and nothing is displayed on the group to indicate it has happened either.

There is a basic web UI provided for organizations though, if you install this CKAN extension: https://github.com/datagovuk/ckanext-hierarchy (I'd encourage people to improve it and submit Pull Requests)

It shouldn't be too difficult to adapt this to groups and I'd encourage you to do this on a fork of ckanext-hierarchy and do a Pull Request when it is working.